# How to check if div with class is the last element

Tags: jquery

So here is an issue with jquery. How can I know if the div with specific class is the last element. I have following html

```
<div class="main">

    <div class="check"></div>
    <div class="check"></div>
    <div class="check"></div>
    <div class="check"></div>

</div>
```

I am doing like this

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.next-work', function() {

    var next = jQuery('.display-work').next('.check');
    jQuery('.check').removeClass('display-work');

    if (next) {
        next.addClass('display-work');
    } else {
        jQuery('.main .check:first').addClass('display-work');
    }

    jQuery('.display-work').find('.full-work-container').show();
});
```

That means I don't want to stop adding class into div when clicking something like a slider. If the element is in the html, it should automatically add class to first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i know if the div with specific class is the last element

```
if($(this).is(':last-child'))
{
  // i am last child
}
```

Comment: working nice but the issue is if i select the last div only then it is not working

Comment: It is meant to be true for only last element

Answer (score 7):

For something more complex, let's say you have more classes, elements or divs inside and u just want the last of all the checks:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="check"></div>
    <div class="check"></div>
    <div class="check"></div>
    <div class="check"></div>
    <div class="NotACheck"></div>
    <button>Just a button</button>
</div>
```

Use

```
if ( $(this).is($(".check:last")) ) 
{
   // I'm the last check element!
}
```